# Crystal Reports bobj is not defined VS 2012 and Windows 10

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, crystal-reports

I had Laptop with Windows 8 and VS 2012, my project with Asp.net and Crystal reports was working fine. After I bought new laptop with Windows 10 but Crystal reports has stop vewing in my browser and I found error by using browser debugger that is 'ReferenceError: bobj is not defined'.
I tried the following:

- I installed and checked with CRforVS_13_0_15, CRforVS_13_0_18, CRforVS_13_0_20 but no success.

  - Copy asp_client folder in my project root directory
  - call reference to "aspnet_client/system_web/4_0_30319/crystalreportviewers13/js/crviewer/crv.js in my MasterPage header
  - Enable .Net 3.5  in Windows features.

Note: But the same Project and reports are working/viewing fine in Server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I installed [ServicePack21](https://wiki.scn.sap.com/wiki/display/BOBJ/Crystal+Reports%2C+Developer+for+Visual+Studio+Downloads) and upgraded all the reports in my Project. Remove all references in Web.Config file and Re-add references of CrystalReports to my project.